# \n Not Working For Linebreak -- Java

Tags: java, swing, line-breaks

I am using the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Finder extends JFrame
{
       JPanel jp = new JPanel();
       JLabel jl = new JLabel("Credits: Andrew / JellyBellyFred");
       JTextField jt = new JTextField("Enter A Player Name, Then Press 'Find Skin'!", 30);
       JButton jb = new JButton("Find Skin");
       JLabel lnbreak = new JLabel("\n");

       public Finder()
       {
              setTitle("Minecraft Skin Finder");
              setVisible(true);
              setSize(500, 200);
              setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              setResizable(false);

              jp.add(jt);
              jp.add(lnbreak);
              jp.add(jb);
              jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
              {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                      {
                             String input = jt.getText();
                             jl.setText("http://minecraft.aggenkeech.com/player/" + input);
                      }
              });

              jp.add(jl);
              add(jp);

       }


       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
             Finder t = new Finder();
       }
}
```

To try to get a new window that will look like this:

**[Input Box]**

[Button]

--TEXT--

But for some reason it always turns out like this:

**[Input Box]  [Button]**

--TEXT--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the following works in GUI. But there is no harm in trying it out.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Use the above code in place of `"\n"`. In labels, I have tried few html tags which worked like a charm. Try this one and provide your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead? 
This way you can organize your UI elements exactly how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use "linebreaker" in GUI. GUI are designed different way. If you want to output as suggested, use Layouts. You can put more panels inside each other to get desired effect, each with different layout.

Or second solution, but not sure if it works in Java, is to use absolute positioning. You set coordinates of "boxes" manually. But this is not really good solution.